# Como llamar una clase que se conecta a SQL para poner ejecutar un Sp con c#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, conexión

Buen dia, estoy trabajando en un desarrollo con c# en visual studio. necesito que al presionar un boton se ejecute un procedimiento almacenado que esta en una base de datos en sql. este es el codigo de la clase que se conecta a la base de datos

namespace Conexionsqlserver
{
class conexionbd //Conexion a la base de datos
{

```
    public static SqlConnection conectar() //Constructor de la clase
    {
        SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("Server=PRUEBA; Initial Catalog=PRUEBA1; Integrated Security=True");
        conexion.Open();
        return conexion;
    }
     
    public void abrir() // Captura de errores
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Conexion abierta");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("Error al conectar a la bd" + ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Pero en el codigo del boton al llamar a la clase Conexionbd, me sale error y no me permite utilizar la conexion para poder ejecutar el SP

```
    private void btnEjecutar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conexionbd.conexion();

        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("ds_sp_PruebaDesarrolloJuan", conexionbd); aqui al pasar el nombre de la conexion me sale error CS0119 
        sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        // Ejecuta el sp, el número de filas afectadas ya no se puede reflejar aquí y siempre devuelve -1
        int count = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Alguien sabe como puedo llamar esa clase para poder que tome el parametro en el SQLCommand

Comment: Y el texto del error?

Comment: si que pena, el erro sale en la linea de SqlCommand, cuando le paso el nombre de la conexion, me sale que "conexionbd" es tipo, que no es validad en el contexto indicado

Comment: Suena a un error de compilación y que el proyecto no corre debido a esto, correcto? En cuál línea está ocurriendo el error? Estás seguro que `conexionbd` es de tibo `SqlConnection`? Por favor lee la [documentación de SQLConnection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) para verificar que la estás utilizando correctamente

Comment: el metodo estatico se llama conectar, no conexion... si no pones el error, imposible ayudarte mas....